# How work the p-value simulation in the chisq.test() and fisher.test()

Tags: r, simulation, contingency

I have contingency tables RxC. How  `chisq.test` and `fisher.test` functions work when called with arguments `simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 5000` ?

I'm using the code below to validate the association (or independence) in the contingency table `DATA`:

```
 chisq.test(DATA, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 5000, correct = FALSE)
 fisher.test(DATA,hybrid = TRUE, simulate.p.value = TRUE)
```

I know that the test can perform Monte Carlo simulations to estimate the p-value of the test, what I want to know is how these simulations are done internally, that is, if the simulations are made to arrive at a normal distribution or another distribution to deliver the p-value at the end of the test?

Comment: The usual reply on rhelp mailing list would be to look at the code and explain what difficulty you are having understanding specific parts.

Comment: Agree with @42-: can you please be more specific? "How [does it] work" is pretty vague ...

Comment: I know that the test can perform Monte Carlo simulations to estimate the P value of the test, what I want to know is how these simulations are done internally, that is, if the simulations are made to arrive at a normal distribution or another distribution to deliver the P value at the end of the test

Comment: They almost certainly would not involve approximating a Normal distribution since that is a continuous distribution. You should probably search on hypergeometric distributions.

Comment: @Jonas, could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `chisq.test` and `fisher.test` p-value simulation is carried out in a non-parametric way without prior distribution assumption. Please see the excerpt of source code for `chisq.test`:

```
if (simulate.p.value) {
    setMETH()
    nx <- length(x)
    sm <- matrix(sample.int(nx, B * n, TRUE, prob = p), 
                 nrow = n)
    ss <- apply(sm, 2L, function(x, E, k) {
      sum((table(factor(x, levels = 1L:k)) - E)^2/E)
    }, E = E, k = nx)
    PARAMETER <- NA
    PVAL <- (1 + sum(ss >= almost.1 * STATISTIC))/(B + 1)
}
```